# Change the variable value using sed command in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm finding a `sed` command in linux that can replace the following variable value to `root` in .env file

```
DB_USERNAME=123
DB_ABC_USERNAME=abc
DB_ABC_DEF_USERNAME=abcdef
```

to

```
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_ABC_USERNAME=root
DB_ABC_DEF_USERNAME=root
```

the file have another variable within such like DB_HOST=xxx, we can not using sed change all variable

Comment: by the way, the file have another variable within such like `DB_HOST=xxx`,
wh can not using sed change all variable

Comment: @anubhava yes !

Comment: `sed -E 's/^(DB_USERNAME|DB_ABC_USERNAME|DB_ABC_DEF_USERNAME)=.*/\1=root/' file`

Comment: @Fan, please check answer too once on same.

Comment: @Fan add the `DB_HOST=xxx` detail to question.. and you're expected to show what you've tried to solve this yourself..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I getting a better answer

```
sed -i '/DB_.*USERNAME/s/=.*/=root/g'  .env
```

I think this is a good question but why dislike?

Comment: if you hover over downvote button on question it says: "**This question does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or not useful"... see also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 0):

This simple `sed` will help you on same.

```
sed 's/=.*/=root/g'  Input_file
```

In case you want to save the output into same Input_file then use `sed -i` option in above code too.

***EDIT:*** In case you want to look for specific strings values to be only searched and substituted then following may help you on same.

```
sed -E '/(DB_USERNAME)|(DB_ABC_USERNAME)|(DB_ABC_DEF_USERNAME)/s/=.*/=root/g'  Input_file
```

***EDIT2:*** In case you are looking for specific strings only to be changed then following may help you on same.

```
awk '/DB_USERNAME/||/DB_ABC_USERNAME/||/DB_ABC_DEF_USERNAME/{sub(/=.*/,"=root")} 1'  Input_file
```

Add `> temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file` in above code in case you want to save the output in same Input_file itself.

Comment: I getting the error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 64: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: @Fan, try `awk` till that `sed` is working fine for me.

Comment: awk  way is run success but nothing to change
`sudo /usr/local/bin/docker-compose exec laravel sh -c "

            awk '/DB_USERNAME/||/DB_ABC_USERNAME/||/DB_ABC_DEF_USERNAME/{sub(/=.*/,\"=root\")} 1'  .env
        "`

Comment: @Fan, as suggested in post too to save changes in file use `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file`, it should FLY then.